# Downloading File From S3 Fails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having some major problems when with a script I have to download files from S3.

The problem I'm encountering is that every time I try to download a file, the download starts perfectly, but about halfway through a download the file just stops. Every time. On every file. These are video files, so a lot of them are significantly big. Not sure what to do or how to approach this. Here's my script:

```
<?php
    // other code exists; this is the main download logic
    set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(false);
    ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

    $chunk = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // bytes per chunk (10 MB)

    $fh = fopen($video->getMp4Source(), "rb");

    if ($fh === false) {
        echo "Unable open file";
    }

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-type: MP4');
    header('Content-length: ' . $video->getFileSize());
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$video->getMp4Source().'"');

    while (!feof($fh)) {
        echo fread($fh, $chunk);

        ob_flush();  // flush output
        flush();
    }

    exit;
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, or why it keeps happening. There are no errors being logged, and no errors are occurring outside from the file failing to complete its download. I have tried this with readfile(), but it was using up too many resources and it wasn't completing, regardless.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why don't you just give the direct S3 url instead of piping it through PHP? Alternatively, consider using a proxy.

Comment: We only allow users to download the file, after a specific process is complete. We need them to hit our URL that will force the download to happen. There's validation that happens on our side, so proxying is not an option.

Comment: Then do a redirect instead.

Comment: Here is a relevant article from the AWS PHP blog that might be useful in this use case: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2C4WJBMSMW68A/Streaming-Amazon-S3-Objects-From-a-Web-Server

Comment: So, that's all on me. We receive several encodings from a video provider, and we were using the wrong file size, which was actually causing the content-length to be incorrect (twice the size of what we were expecting).

Thanks Jeremy! You pointing out that link definitely helped me find the problem!